# MongoEngine & serverStatus

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I am switching my python script from using pymongo to using mongoengine.  Previously, I had this call:

`client_count = db.command("serverStatus")["connections"]['current'] - 1`

but I want to get the number of current connections using mongoengine's wrapper instead.  I looked at [server-status](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/server-status/) and the mongoengine [docs](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apireference.html) and was unable to find an equivalent call for pulling server variables.

I want to swap over to mongoengine because we're using its ODM features and we would like to cut out redundancy.

Any pointers for this?  What is the correct syntax, if at all?  Thanks.

In the meantime, we are just going to use pymongo for getting the correct data, while using mongoengine for everything else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no Mongoengine equivalent, so you have to call this manually.  As we wrap pymongo you can do the call via getting the database from the connection register.  The easiest way to do this is to use the document class  eg:

```
db = Document._get_db()
client_count = db.command("serverStatus")["connections"]['current'] - 1
```

Comment: Both Ross & acm gave very helpful answers w/ precise wording -- thank you both!!  The code snippet makes sense and sheds insight into the inner workings.

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: I don't know either of these APIs well.

However, if you look at the dependencies of mongoengine, you will see that it depends on pymongo, since it is in fact implemented in terms of pymongo.

Now have a look at mongoengines implementation of its connection logic: https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/master/mongoengine/connection.py#L113: the connection objects it returns are actually pymongo connections. So, in principle, you should be able to make pymongo calls on the returned connection. So you could in fact continue to use the above call. Of course, you are violating the encapsulation of mongoengine at this point, since mongoengine could change its internal implementation type for connections.

However, looking through their documentation, I don't see any other way to access this aspect of the database, so perhaps this is the easiest way forward.